# Selecting a WebElement With a Fluid ID?

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have an application which I am trying to test with WebDriver. On one page, the user selects a data source and some other options and then clicks next. When the user clicks next, they are presented with a page which has a list of documents that they must upload prior to submitting a request.

On the page with the documents that they must upload I am attempting to get the names of the documents and then compare them with a spreadsheet which has the list of required documents based on the data source the user chooses.

Here is my problem, I am trying to get the document names off the website. I first tried it with

```
String docOne = driver.findElement(By.xpath(/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/h5)).getAttribute("textContent").toString();
System.out.println(docOne);
```

When I run this, it cannot find the element.

I then tried the following:

```
String docOne = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('41027')/div[1]/h5")).getAttribute("textContent").toString();
System.out.println(docOne);
```

When I ran this, it could not find the element, I then manually tested this and found that every new request has a new ID, even though the first xpath I tested does not change.

My question then is, how do I get this to work? Since the element changes everytime I run the test?

Answer (score 0):

I apparently had some brain flatulence this morning.

When automation clicks next to get to the documents page the page is scrolled all the way to the bottom and the top elements apparently cannot be found. I put a long delay 30 seconds and scrolled to the top of the page manually and the test passed with the first xpath I mentioned.

So I selected a web element which is always visible and told it to do a send keys with a page Up command, and it worked swimmingly.